# cygwin Xserver losing connection

Tags: ssh, cygwin, xserver

I am running Xserver on cygwin (on top on Windows 7), and then using `xterm` to remote to linux via `ssh -X`, and run remote applications there, like `konsole`, `emacs` and others.

Initially all works fine, e.g. executing `emacs` pops up the correctly working window on my Windows 7 box.

But if I try to run the same emacs some time (like an hour) later, I get a linux message
`Display localhost:10.0 unavailable, simulating -nw`
and `emacs` runs in-line.

I have checked and the Xserver seems still up and running ok. Indeed, if I exit out to the original cygwin and reconnect to Linux by ssh -X again, it works just fine.

Would you know what is happening and how can it be fixed? Why is my Xserver connection being dropped?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel like a total moron to ask a question and answer it myself, but for the same of a future reference, here is a work around that helped. Instead of using `ssh -X`, if `ssh -Y` is used instead, it works better and does not drop the ability to spawn new windows over time.